# Apache passenger setup - Multiple projects under same domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, phusion-passenger

I want to setup different projects under same domain with different ruby version for each app.

Eg:

- example1.com is a **main app** which runs on Ruby 1.8.7
- example1.com/tasks is another app which runs on Ruby 1.9.2

I tried some of the setup in apache2 using "alias" as discussed in some of the posts here [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19090608/apache-virtualhosts-different-paths-serve-different-application-on-same-ip),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30813207/apache2-need-multiple-projects-with-same-domain-that-use-different-path-after-d) but sub apps are not working(not loading passenger but its serving the static files).

My configuration looks like this,

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /home/rails_apps/mainapp
        Alias /tasks /home/rails_apps/tasks
        <Directory /home/rails_apps/tasks>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

How do I load(passenger) different ruby version with in the same virtual host ?

- OS: RHEL 5
- Apache 2.2
- passenger 4
- RVM

Answer (score 1):

You want to deploy /tasks and /search in sub-URIs. See [the Passenger deployment guide.](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/apache/deploy/ruby/#deploying-an-app-to-a-sub-uri)